# different picture for different screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I got at problem! I have used `<picture>` in my html and I see now that it is not supported in Safari and IE. I have one image for browser `max-width: 660px` and a new image for browser `min-width: 660px`. Do anyone have some suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <!-- Use CSS media queries in media attribute (this will show for screens less than 661px) -->
  <source srcset="http://lorempixel.com/660/200"  media="(max-width: 660px)">

  <!-- Default image (this will show for screens greater than 660px) -->
  <source srcset="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400">

  <!-- Use this image if <picture> element isn't supported -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400" />
</picture>
```

Comment: That code is the one i have used but is not supported in Safari and IE.

Comment: You can use [Picturefill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to add `picture` support in older browsers.